# How do I make the find command not prefix results with ./?

Tags: linux, find

I am just beginner to shell scripting.

By running below command i am getting output as below

```
$ cd demo
$ ls
dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4 dir5
$
$find . -mtime -2 -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/(dir1|dir2|dir3|dir4|dir5)/.+" -exec ls {} \; > /tmp/basefileslist
./dir1/demo1.sh
./dir2/demo2.sh
./dir3/demo3.sh
./dir4/demo4.sh
./dir5/demo5.sh
```

I should get output without `./` —
I want like below

```
dir1/demo1.sh
dir2/demo2.sh
dir3/demo3.sh
dir4/demo4.sh
dir5/demo5.sh
```

Comment: Are you using the output of the `find` command for something, and is that why you want to modify it? The output of `find` can not generally be safely parsed since Unix filenames can contain newlines. It is therefore better to use `find` with its `-exec` predicate to execute whatever it is you need to run on the found files. See also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697).  If you don't care about that, then there is nothing stopping you from passing the output through `sed 's/..//'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the `find` command to remove the `./` prefix from the output by using the GNU-specific (but then again your `-regextype` is also GNU-specific) `-printf` predicate instead of `-exec`. Here's an example command that should give you the desired output:

```bash
find . -mtime -2 \
       -type f \
       -regextype posix-egrep \
       -regex '.*/(dir1|dir2|dir3|dir4|dir5)/.+' \
       -printf '%P\n' > /tmp/basefileslist
```

In this command, the `-printf '%P\n'` predicate is used to print the relative path of each file found by `find`, without the leading `./` prefix. The `%P` format specifier specifies the relative path (relative to the directory you told it to start from, here `.`), and  `\n` specifies that each path should be printed on a new line.

After running this command, the output should be similar to the following:

```bash
dir1/demo1.sh
dir2/demo2.sh
dir3/demo3.sh
dir4/demo4.sh
dir5/demo5.sh
```

Comment: Perfectly working after adding printf , Thank you so much Cyborg!

Answer (score 4):

The `./` in find's output comes from the `.` argument before the options.  Changing the `.` argument changes the part of the output you're focused on.  Given your example, this would produce the output you're asking for:

```
find dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4 dir5 -mtime -2 -type f -exec ls {} \;
```

I excluded the regex options because I guessed that they duplicate the action of specifying the subdirectory arguments.  The output is:

```
dir1/demo1.sh
dir2/demo2.sh
dir3/demo3.sh
dir4/demo4.sh
dir5/demo5.sh
```

In your particular test case (with only five matching subdirs), you can reduce the list of subdirectories to a simple shell glob:

```
find dir[1-5] -mtime -2 -type f -exec ls {} \;
```

Or an even shorter glob:

```
find dir? -mtime -2 -type f -exec ls {} \;
```

There are many use cases where using `find dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4 dir5` or `find dir?` won't find the desired files like this.  But the point of my answer was to show how the arguments before the options will affect the paths in find's output.